# Stored objects/files of Minio do not appear in local disk

Tags: file-permissions, bucket, minio, object-storage

I have created a folder in root direcoty, i.e. `/data/test` and I have already given full permissions to this folder using:

```
chmod 775 /data/test
```

Than I started MinIO, and from Minio GUI console, I created a bucket called `mybucket` and placed a txt file inside this bucket.

Note the mount path I passed to start MinIO server is `/data/test`.

I assume that the normal behavior is the txt file to appear in `/data/test`. However, the local folder is empty: `ls /data/test/` returns nothing.

Where the txt file is actually reside on my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used a `StatefulSet` with `volumeClaimTemplates` which is deprecated.

Instead, I used a PV and a PVC and the problem is solved.

**PV and PVC**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  namespace: ches
  name: ches-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: edge-pv-class
  local:
    path: /data/test
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: ches-worker
          operator: In
          values:
          - "true"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: edge-claim
  namespace: ches
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: edge-pv-class
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
```

**StatefulSet**

```
volumeMounts:
- name: data
  mountPath: /data
```